# Unzip folder by chunks in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, unzip

I have a big zip file containing many files that i'd like to unzip by chunks to avoid consuming too much memory.

I tried to use python module `zipfile` but I didn't find a way to load the archive by chunk and to extract it on disk.

Is there simple way to do that in python ?

**EDIT**

@steven-rumbalski correctly pointed that `zipfile` correctly handle big files by unzipping the files one by one without loading the full archive.

My problem here is that my zip file is on AWS S3 and that my EC2 instance cannot load such a big file in RAM so I download it by chunks and I would like to unzip it by chunk.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a special way to extract a large archive to disk.  The source [Lib/zipfile.py](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.6/Lib/zipfile.py) shows that `zipfile` is already memory efficient.  Creating a `zipfile.ZipFile` object does not read the whole file into memory.  Rather it just reads in the table of contents for the ZIP file.  `ZipFile.extractall()` extracts files *one at a time* using `shutil.copyfileobj()` copying from a subclass of `io.BufferedIOBase`.

If all you want to do is a one-time extraction Python provides a shortcut from the command line:

```
python -m zipfile -e archive.zip target-dir/
```

Comment: You're right zipfile handles that pretty well. But my context is a little bit more complicated. The point is that my zip files are on a S3 server and that I can't load full zip because the instance cannot handle it in RAM so i download the zip file by chunk and I'd like to unzip it by chunk

Comment: You don't need to have an entire file in RAM. You still need to have an entire file _on disk_, since zip handling requires seeks inside the file. To download a file to a disk, you also don't need to read it whole into memory; reading it by chunks and writing it by chunks to a temporary file, and then working with this file, should suffice.

Comment: Thx @9000, you're right too. I just expected I could avoid writing the file on disk.

Comment: Do you still need enough memory to hold the largest file in the zip in memory, or does zipFile also chunk writing to disk memory-efficiently by chunking the write command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use zipfile (or possibly tarfile) as follows:

```
import zipfile

def extract_chunk(fn, directory, ix_begin, ix_end):
    with zipfile.ZipFile("{}/file.zip".format(directory), 'r') as zf:
        infos = zf.infolist()
        print(infos)
        for ix in range(max(0, ix_begin), min(ix_end, len(infos))):
                zf.extract(infos[ix], directory)
        zf.close()

directory = "path"
extract_chunk("{}/file.zip".format(directory), directory, 0, 50)
```

Comment: Parameters `ix_begin` and `ix_end` don't seem to be used. (Also, this seems to try to solve a different problem than the OP states.)